# android + phonegap combo box

Tags: android-emulator, cordova

I tried to create a combo box using  in HTML for building an android phone gap application. Its working perfectly on a browser.But on an emulator the click function fails. Kindly please let me know on what could be the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to trigger from 'tap' events instead of 'click'